Install poetry in environments in Azure ML
I am creating an environment which has poetry installed, in Azure ML.
I am totally new to docker and don't understand venv much either.
Below is the code I have written in the docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04
RUN pip install azureml-mlflow
FROM python:3.11-alpine as base

ARG DEV=false
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv \
    PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN apk update && \
    apk add libpq


FROM base as builder

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

RUN apk update && \
    apk add musl-dev build-base gcc gfortran openblas-dev

WORKDIR /app

# Install Poetry
RUN pip install poetry==1.6.1

# Install the app
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN if [ $DEV ]; then \
      poetry install --with dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR; \
    else \
      poetry install --without dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR; \
    fi


FROM base as runtime

COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

COPY src ./src

WORKDIR /app/src

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "app.main"]

I got an error saying this:
2024-12-05T21:11:06: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat pyproject.toml: file does not exist

What am I doing wrong here?
I have not uploaded anything into any folders on Azure ML
Please help

Your error says your pyproject.toml file is missing.  When you biuld this Dockerfile, it wants to copy 2 files: pyproject.toml and poetry.lock.  If those two files are not present in the directory, then you will not be able to build the image. It's important to not add either file to the ".dockerignore" file.
Once you add a pyproject.toml file, or remove that from the .dockerignore file, you'll be able to build.

Thanks for your reply! Should I add the pyproject file to folder where I have all the notebooks?
I have a pyproject file from the poetry run I did on my local machine. Should I use that one here?

You add your pyproject.toml, poetry.lock into your docker context folder.

Above is where you can upload or create new environment giving the folder.
Here, in my case i given folder consists of
Dockerfile and requirements.txt similarly
your folder should contain below files and folder.
pyproject.toml,poetry.lock and src

Thanks for your reply.. I am uploading the pysproject.toml and project.lock files from my local machine, these are the ones that got created when I set up poetry on the local machine. What does inside the src folder?

I added pyproject.toml and project.lock files and tried to run it. it gave me this error:
The command '/bin/sh -c if [ $DEV ]; then       poetry install --with dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR;     else       poetry install --without dev --no-root && rm -rf $POETRY_CACHE_DIR;     fi' returned a non-zero code: 1
CalledProcessError(1, ['docker', 'build', '-f', 'Dockerfile', '.', '-t', '2be918c79da.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_ddfdd2635c21d567a4a70', '-t', '2bfe918c79da.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_ddfdd263d567a4a70:1'])
Building docker image failed with exit code: 1

scroll up to see the exact error and add those details here.
